# c# ToString() - printing child items

Tags: c#, collections, parent-child, tostring

I have a class (eg. `Foo`)which which overrides ToString method to print it's internal state. This class has a collection of `Foo` - it's child elements. Children can also have children etc.

I'm looking for solution to implement in ToString() in such way that it would indent child elements automatically, eg:

```
Parent Foo
 Child1 Foo
  Child1.1 Foo
 Child2 Foo
  Child2.1 Foo
  Child2.2 Foo
```

Comment: Do you mean that calling `ToString` on the root should print the entire tree of `ToString` calls?

Comment: I don't suppose each `Foo` object tracks it's depth in the tree

Comment: Yes, and determine indent level automatically.

Comment: This might not be a great idea. What should happen if there is a circular reference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is to use `ToString()` only as the "entry point" that is called on the root of the subtree to output. That `ToString()` method can call a private `ToIndentedString(int)` method that takes the current indentation level as an argument. That method will then return the string representation of the current node at the specified indentation, plus the string representations of all child nodes at the indentation + 1 etc.

```
public string ToString()
{
    return ToIndentedString(0);
}

private string ToIndentedString(int indentation)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    result.Append(' ', indentation);
    result.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    foreach (Foo child in children) {
        result.Append(child.ToIndentedString(indentation + 1));
    }
    return result.ToString();
}
```

Comment: If you expect a non-trivial size of the tree also consider passing the `StringBuilder` recursively, instead of having one per node, as it will be more efficient.

Comment: @Servy: Absolutely right, great comment :-)

Comment: in the foreach, the call to child.ToIndentedString will not work as the method is private.

Comment: @Jastill: The method is called from within the same class, so what's the matter with it being `private`? Have you tried whether it works? Note that, as per the question, `child` is of type `Foo`, as well.

Comment: I appologise, i just tested it, I would have expected that to fail as you are not calling your own method, but a childs private method and the method is not static.

Comment: @Jastill: Well, it technically is *my own method*, as `child` is of the same type as what I'm writing there. `private` visibility is per class, not per instance (and the compiler couldn't know whether `child` points to a "visible" instance, anyway).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `IFormattable` on `Foo` like this:

```
public class Foo : IFormattable
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public IList<Foo> InnerList { get; set; } 

    public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(format)) format = "0";
        if (formatProvider == null) formatProvider = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;

        int indent = 0;
        Int32.TryParse(format, out indent);
        string indentString = "";
        while(indent > indentString.Length)
        {
            indentString += " ";
        }
        var toString = String.Format("{0}{1}", indentString, Text);
        foreach (Foo foo in InnerList ?? new List<Foo>())
        {
            toString += String.Format("\n{0}", foo.ToString((indent + 1).ToString(), formatProvider));
        }
        return toString;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ToString("0", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    }
}
```

In this case you can also do:

```
String.Format("{0:5}", foo); // Start with 5 indents
```

Or

```
foo.ToString("7", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture); // Also start with indents (7 in this case)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string spacing = "  ";
string newLineSpacing = string.Format("{0}{1}", Environment.NewLine, spacing);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("mydata");
foreach (Foo child in children)
{
    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    sb.Append(spacing);
    sb.Append(child.ToString().Replace(Environment.NewLine, newLineSpacing));
}
```

Untested as I'm currently rebuilding my development machine.